# Laravel eager loading - relationship query

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4

Say I have this 3 tables Blog, Post, Comment which has corresponding models Blog, Post, Comment.
No here is the relation between them:

```
Blog has many Post,  posts()
Post belongs to Blog, blog()  
Post has many Comment, comments() 
Comment belongs to Post post()
```

Now I want to execute some query like this:

```
Blog::with(array('posts.comments' => function($q)
    {
       //query Post columns
    })->find(1);
```

As I know the `$q` is corresponding to the Comment table. Is there any way to query the Post table?

Comment: You want to fetch only comments or both posts and comments?

Comment: Both comments and posts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query nested relation like this:

```
$blog = Blog::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
   $q->where('column','value'); // query posts table
}, 'posts.comments' => function ($q) {
   $q->where('commentsColumn','anotherValue'); // query comments table
}])->find(1);
```

Eloquent will load posts accordingly, only then will it fetch the comments for those posts.

Comment: One for posts and another for comments. Eloquent will not run another query for the relation it already loaded.

Comment: So in your solution I will see blog with post and for each post I will see nested corresponding comments?